# PFUsers are sharing all the same PFObjects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfobject, pfuser

Below are images to explain;

User 1 Logs in and sees the following based on the [PFUser currentUser].username;

[image][image]

However, if I register a new account and login as User 2 the same data is shared, and the name is changed in accordance to the [PFUser currentUser].username;

[image]
[image]

Im sure there is a method, but I'm not sure how exactly, on how do ensure any PFObjects being altered after logging in and securing a PFUser ID, are only associated with THAT user?

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected. You should store the image along with the user that uploaded it. The label `Uploaded by: *username*` should be built with `"Uploaded by: " + photoUploader.username` not `"Uploaded by: " + PFUser.currentUser.username`

Comment: Would that for example if user 1 uploaded images 1-2-3 remove images 1-2-3 from the view if I was to log in with user 2? or Would it simply just change the names of the upload name?

I ideally want to have it so each user only sees what they uploaded?

Comment: There's no context in your question. What does image 1, 2 and 3 mean ? Are they uploaded by a specific user ? Are they displayed in a collection view ? If so, of course it needs to be reloaded after the user logs in.

Comment: Apologies nathan, I have quiet abit of code and wasn't sure which part to highlight and I'm hesitant on copy and pasting the whole code as people have often down voted me for using too much code. However, I fixed the problem - thanks for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding  `[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];`

```
-(void)getReportImages{
//Fetch images
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"ReportImageObject"];

[query orderByDescending:KEY_CREATION_DATE];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.reportsObjectArray = nil;
        self.reportsObjectArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        [self loadReportViews];
    } else {
        [self showErrorView:error];
    }
}];
}
```